# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript, html

В ЧЕМ ОШИБКА. как исправить?

```js
function CheckTest() {
  var qCounts = parseInt(document.getElementById('sQuestionsCount').innerHTML);
  var maxScore = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sMaxPoints').innerHTML);
  var curScore = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= qCounts; i++) {
    var ansCounts = document.getElementById('dqres' + i).getAttribute('answerscount');
    var scoringType = document.getElementById('dqres' + i).getAttribute('scoringtype');
    var answertype = document.getElementById('dqres' + i).getAttribute('answertype');
    var iFilled = false;
    for (var j = 1; j <= ansCounts; j++) {
      var input = document.getElementById('ans' + i + "-" + j);
      if (answertype == "10") {
        if (input.checked) {
          iFilled = true;
          if (scoringType == "0") curScore = curScore + parseInt(input.getAttribute("score"));
        }
      }
```

```html
<input id="bntcheck" type="button" onclick="CheckTest(" ");" value="Перевірити" class="otp-test-checkresult-btn"></input>
<div id="dResults" class="otp-test-results">
  <span class="otp-test-results-header">Ваш результат:</span>
  <div class="otp-test-results-vals">
    <span class="otp-test-results-text">Кількість балів:</span>
    <span id="sScore" class="otp-test-results-value"></span><br />
    <span class="otp-test-results-text">Відсоток рішення:</span>
    <span id="sPercent" class="otp-test-results-value"></span><br />
    <span class="otp-test-results-text">Оцінка:</span>
    <span id="ocenka" class="otp-test-results-value"></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var input = document.getElementById('ans' + i + "-" + j);
> ```

Нет такого элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Всё что я могу сказать по вашей проблеме, так это то, что не правильно отрабатывает строка

```
var input = document.getElementById('ans' + i + "-" + j);
```

То есть не правильно формируется идентификатор `'ans' + i + "-" + j`, судя по всему такого элемента просто нет. Предлагаю вывести результат в консоль. Добавив после приведённой строки строку

```
console.log('ans' + i + "-" + j)
```

И убедиться в том, что элемент с таким идентификатором действительно есть на странице